# Extract specific strings from the df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to format the result of a data frame to look more readable.
The df looks like this:

```
lack_of_minutes['Period'] = pd.to_datetime(lack_of_minutes['time']) - lack_of_minutes['START_TIME']
```

The lack_of_minutes df is type timedelta64[ns].

To avoid the error TypeError: Timedelta('0 days 01:08:12') is not JSON serializable i returned the json like this:

```
return json.dumps(data_load, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
```

Basically it just converts everything it doesn't know to strings

But the format that it's returning the time it's like this: `0 days 17:25:35`
I would like to exclude the 0 days and return only the time.  `17:25:35` to be more readable.
My first idea was to slice the df but didn't work.

What is the correct approach to do this. I am using python 2.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the object you have is a `pandas._libs.tslib.Timedelta`, which is not JSON serializable (AFAIK). If you all you want to do is strip the 'days' part and only have HH:MM:SS, you can do this using string manipulation.

```
import pandas as pd

# create a dummy Timedelta
d = datetime.datetime(2017,11,21,12,30) - datetime.datetime(2017,11,20,23,59)

print str(pd.to_timedelta(d))[-8:]
```

Output:

```
'12:31:00'
```

In your dataframe, you can convert your column to a string in this format by applying this function. I recommend creating a new column (instead of overwriting) so you can make sure your output is what you expect.

```
# new column is a string HH:MM:SS
lack_of_minutes['NewPeriod'] = lack_of_minutes['Period'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[-8:])
```

Keep in mind that this will always drop the days part of your string, even if it's not 0.